# ListView with Efficiency adapter notifyDataSetChanged() causes listview to dissapear?

Tags: android

I have a similar question going because I had the same problem with the `listview` in an `AlertDialog`. so now I suspect something else is wrong. All I am doing is removing a single item from the `arraylist` and calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` in my efficiency adapter. The `ListView` completely disappears but I can still get a valid count via `getCount()` and even pull items from the dang list! So... the `ListView` is still active but it's not visible in my view... what the hell? This code is the exact same efficiency adapter I am using in my main activity and I call `notifyDataSetChanged()` exactly the same way in that activity with no issues. This is driving me nuts for 2 days now. Has anyone ever seen anything like this?

EDIT: I was able to fix the issue with a large amount of unnecessary and elaborate hacks... :P

Comment: And how did you fix it?  I'm having the same trouble in one app but not in another and I can't see any difference in my code - in fact most of it was copied and pasted from the working app!

Comment: This question is quite old. You should probably ask your own question. And this should be a comment.

Comment: I ended up making a completely different adapter class that implements observer/observable

http://androidworkz.com/2010/08/13/smart-list-adapter-tutorial-singleton-oberservable-list-objects-and-how-they-can-improve-your-app/

http://androidworkz.com/2010/08/14/beyond-smart-lists-how-observable-singletons-change-the-game/